# How can I make a preview of a video?

Tags: ffmpeg

Please help to compose a command in the terminal. I want to make random slicing of video pieces for 2 seconds throughout the entire length of the file. Resize video to 640x480 and remove all audio. I end up wanting a 16 seconds mp4 video file without audio. Now I need to do 3 commands:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select='between(t,235,238)+between(t,490,493)+between(t,870,873)+between(t,1200,1203)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -af "aselect='between(t,235,238)+between(t,490,493)+between(t,870,873)+between(t,1200,1203)',asetpts=N/SR/TB" out.mp4

ffmpeg -i /out.mp4 -s 600x338 -c:a copy resize.mp4

ffmpeg -i /resize.mp4 -c copy -an nosound.mp4
```

How can I do this with just one command?

Comment: You're doing three separate operations with ffmpeg, so three separate commands makes sense. You could just put these into a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select='between(t,235,238)+between(t,490,493)+between(t,870,873)+between(t,1200,1203)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,scale=640:-2" -an out.mp4
```